# RegEx to match every occurrence of a certain word but interrupted by certain characters

Tags: java

I'm not a programmer but I'm trying to nail some RegEx. I learned just some basics and not much other.
My intent in this is the following: I have some formatted text in which there are some occurrencies of the word `uses)`. I want to get everything behind `uses)` (and "uses)"), but the match has to stop if it hits `:` or other occurrencies of `uses)`, and also the first white-space (so that the match starts with a non-white-space character).

Example text:

```
Second Wind (Recharge 5-6) (1/1 uses). The Veteran can use a bonus action to regain hit points equal to 14 (1d10 + 9).

Spellcasting.
3/day each: Jump (3/3 uses), Darkness (3/3 uses), Burning Hands (3/3 uses)

Spellcasting.
1st level (4 slots): Ray Of Sickness, Witch Bolt, Tasha's Hideous Laughter (4/4  uses)
```

The RegEx should give me respectively:

```
Second Wind (Recharge 5-6) (1/1 uses)
Jump (3/3 uses)
Darkness (3/3 uses)
Burning Hands (3/3 uses)
Ray Of Sickness, Witch Bolt, Tasha's Hideous Laughter (4/4  uses)
```

Until now I came up with this code.

```
[^:,\s](.*?uses\))
```

This matches almost everything correctly, but unfortunately the match doesn't stop at `:`, thus matching even other text that I don't want to match, getting this instead of what I wrote up here:

```
Second Wind (Recharge 5-6) (1/1 uses)
3/day each: Jump (3/3 uses)
Darkness (3/3 uses)
Burning Hands (3/3 uses)
1st level (4 slots): Ray Of Sickness, Witch Bolt, Tasha's Hideous Laughter (4/4  uses)
```

How can I get rid of that extra text I don't need? Here's the example with the code https://regexr.com/4sbtf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you currently have with `[^:,\s](.*?uses\))` is that the sequence `.*?` matches any character sequence, eventually including the `:`.
What you would want to do is replace the wildcard `.` by "any character but :", i.e. `[^:]`.
`[^:,\s]([^:]*?uses\))` thus achieves what you want.

Comment: Only match `[^:,\s][^:]*?uses\)` or capture `([^:,\s][^:]*?uses\))`.

Comment: Oh man, many thanks! I tried something similiar but I think I didn't remove the `.` and it wasn't working